# Accessing Variables in Javascript using .length

Tags: javascript, variables

I'm pretty new to Javascript, so forgive me if this is a simple question.

I'm trying to access the length of a set of checkboxes in a form using Javascript. However, I need to be able to change the "name" field of the checkboxes to check several different sets of them. Right now, my sample code looks like:

```
var set = "set" + x;
totalLength = optionBoxes.set.length;
```

The variable `x` is being incremented by a `for` loop that wraps the whole thing and the name of the checkbox sets that I'm trying to access are set0, set1, set2, etc.

Thanks.

*Edit: small typo fixes*

Comment: Can you show some sample HTML for a "checkbox set"?

Comment: ... and what is `optionBoxes`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you want this:

```
var set = "set" + x;
totalLength = optionBoxes[set].length;
```

In Javascript, properties of an object are usually accessed as `object.name`, but they can also be accessed by `object["name"]` if you have the name as a string.

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was that simple. I'm so new I can't accept answers yet, but will do so as soon as I'm allowed.

Answer (score 0):

if you think that your code should otherwise work try:

totalLength = optionBoxes[set].length;